# slidespercolumns doesn't work in swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I try to show columns base slider using swiper ver 6.5.8.

HTML:

```
 <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  slidesPerColumn: 2,
  slidesPerGroup: 6,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

But in action `slidesPerColumn` and `slidesPerGroup` doesn't work. howdo can I fix this problem?

In need like this:

[image]

DEMO [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vLxw1uac/)

Answer (score 1):

You have working exemple [here](https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view), take care how you customise it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        grid: {
          rows: 2,
        },
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```